# Framer Motion - How to control animation of style when using MotionValue

Tags: framer-motion

I have a `MotionValue<number>` which I'm setting as `style` on a `motion.div`. How do I control the animation of it?

*I can't find in the docs where to control the duration of the animation.*

```
import { motion, useMotionValue, useTransform, animate } from 'framer-motion';

const x = useMotionValue(0);
const changingX = useTransform(x, [0, 10], [0, 100]);

// change the changingX value when necessary
animate(x, 1);
animate(x, 5);
animate(x, 9);

<motion.div style={{ x: changingX }}></motion.div>
```

Code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-64077992-forked-kfvlur?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an object as the third argument. Here is an example:

```js
animate(x, 100, { duration: 3 });
```

!note that the duration must be specified in seconds